# Bootstrap and ASP.NET Menu

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a navigation bar in my ASP.NET web application, and I am using [bootstrap-3.1.1](http://getbootstrap.com/). In particular I am trying to utilize their nav-tabs as shown [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs). I have done much research on this issue, I have also been unsuccessful with such a scenario in the past. I used [this](http://techbrij.com/responsive-menu-twitter-bootstrap-asp-net) link for reference as it accomplishes a very similar task, but my application is displaying unexpected results. I realize the previous link is for Twitter Bootstrap, but I'd believe the behaviour would be similar if not identical.

I have an ASP menu, as shown below, which displays the items I have added in the desired fashion. I have set the `StaticMenuStyle`, and `StaticSelectedStyle` with the appropriate classes. I have also tried many different permutations of these classes with no success.

Here is my ASP.net code:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavBar" runat="server" role="tablist"
    StaticSubMenuIndent="16px" RenderingMode="List" 
    CssClass="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home" Selected="True"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Generation" Value="Generation"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Loads" Value="Loads"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Tie Line Metering" Value="Tie Line Metering"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="About" Value="About"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
    <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="active" />
</asp:Menu>
```

I have all of the proper `<link>` and `<script>` tags included for bootstrap to work, and I know this because I can create a bare bones version of the nav menu, and it works perfectly. The only thing that doesn't work, is the 'active' tab changing. The barebones code for the list without an ASP menu is as follows:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>About</a></li>
</ul>
```

The only thing that doesn't work with the `<asp:Menu>` is that the proper 'active' styling CSS class is not being applied to the `<li>` items. Instead, on a button press, the 'selected' class is being applied to the anchor (`<a>`) tag within the `<li>` item. Said behaviour is shown here with the 'Home' item being selected. Also, when using the developer tools in chrome I may manually add a `<li>` item to the 'active' CSS class, and it behaves properly. [image: Undesired styling results with ASP menu.]

I also have two lines of jQuery that are removing erroneous class attributes to the menu that cause undesired results that are automatically being inserted by ASP. They are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#NavBar ul, #NavBar ul li, #NavBar ul li a").removeClass('level1 static');
    $("#NavBar, #NavBar ul, #NavBar ul li").removeAttr('style');
</script>
```

Sorry for the lengthy post but I hope I have articulated my problem well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this to add the 'selected' class to the parent li-element:

```
$('#NavBar ul li a.selected').parent().addClass('selected');
```

And to remove the 'selected' class from the a-element add as 2nd line:

```
$('#NavBar ul li a.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

Comment: I just used this in my own project. The exact lines of code are:     $('#NavigationMenu ul li a.selected').parent().addClass('active');
$('#NavigationMenu ul li a.selected').removeClass('selected');

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem and solved it like this:

```
$(function () {
    var menu = $('#NavBar');

    // Fixes for the aspMenu so that it will work with our bootstrap implementation
    menu.find('ul')[0].style = ''; // clear the asp menu's inline styling
    menu.find('ul')[0].className = menu[0].className; // The class name needs to be on the first ul element not the container div
    menu.find('li.static').removeClass('static'); // remove the extraneous class


    menu.find('li.has-popup').addClass('dropdown') //  add the dropdown class to the popup menus
        .find('> ul').addClass('dropdown-menu').attr('style', 'display: none');  // add the appropriate class, and overwrite the extraneous inline styling

    // No styling is required on the container div
    menu[0].style = '';
    menu[0].className = '';
});
```

Hope that helps :)